# Using d3.js to modify c3.js chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, c3.js

I am using C3.js to create charts. I have created a simple donut chart. Here is the screen shot:
[image]

When I hover over the different donut slices/pieces they expand. Here is a screen shot of that happening:

[image]

I was wondering if it is possible to have certain donut pieces expand like that by DEFAULT without hovering over them.

Here is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4k0g7ce3/)

I was also suggested to add the following code to make the donut pieces stick out:

```
setTimeout( function() {
  d3.selectAll('.c3-arc-D, .c3-arc-B, .c3-arc-C').attr("transform", "scale(1.1)");       
}, 5);
```

However this makes the chart messy and the circle is not maintained anymore. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following

```
setTimeout(function () {
    chart.internal.expandArc(['A', 'B'])
}, 0)
```

[Source](https://github.com/c3js/c3/blob/master/src/arc.js#L302-L306)

Note: The ideal solution would be to grab the `mouseover` callback and call it with your data but if you only want to expand the arcs just call the method above

```js
var currentSlice;

var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#dash',
  data: {
    x: 'x',
    columns: [
      ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06'],
      ['A', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
      ['B', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50],
      ['C', 50, 100, 130, 240, 200, 150],
      ['D', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50],
      ['E', 130, 150, 200, 300, 200, 100]
    ],
    type: 'donut'
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'timeseries',
      tick: {
        format: '%Y-%m-%d',
        centered: true,
        position: 'inner-right'
      }
    }
  },
  bar: {
    width: {
      ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    grouped: false,
    contents: function(data, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
      //  console.log("Containt");
      // console.log(data, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color);
      return "<p style='border:1px solid red;'>" + data[0].value + "</p>";

    }
  }
});
setTimeout(function() {
  chart.internal.expandArc(['A', 'B'])
}, 0)
```

```css
p {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  min-width: 91px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.css" />
<div id="dash"></div>
```

Comment: The answer is good however there is one issue with the answer the arcs do expand but once i hover over the chart they shrink again. is there way to fix this?

Comment: @MauricioPoppe - you might need to override `unexpandArc`. https://jsfiddle.net/uamd1404/ is probably one way to do it. Cheers!